# Converting custom string to dictionary python

Tags: python, string

I have an example string from

```
 kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

command output, which looks like

```
  NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP        
 cp-node-1                                   Ready    control-plane   xxx   xxx       xxx     
 cp-node-2                                   Ready    control-plane   xxx   xxx       yyy   
 cp-node-3                                   Ready    control-plane   xxx   xxx       zzz
```

What could be the effective and the quickest way, to extract the output in the format of dictionary

```
 node_ip['cp-node-1'] = xxx (Internal IP)
```

I tried with json and ast, but I believe a custom formatting with regex is required.

Comment: Why not use pandas?

Comment: You don't need a regex. Read each line, use `split()` to turn it into a list of fields, and then index the fields you want. E.g. `node_ip[row[0]] = row[5]`

Comment: kubectl has other output options. Try `-o json` and you'll get something parsable by `json.loads`. That should be easier to build into the format you want.

Comment: @Barmar how can I use pandas to convert a string such as above?

Comment: @tdelaney getting output in json provides lot of unwanted information, compared to wide. Thus filtering out addresses there might be harder. But I'll give it a try

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan JSON is a much more fool-proof format than your preferred space-delimited format, which can easily break when any values contain spaces.

Comment: There is also a `jsonpath` option which I assume can be used to filter data. There may be a performance hit for grabbing the whole json config, but in doing this kind of thing with other tools before, Your situation may be different. it hasn't been a big deal for me. The json is usually easy to filter.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan `pd.read_table()` with appropriate options can parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're tempted to use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) with a *string-based I/O* :

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd #pip install pandas

KEY, VALUE = "NAME", "INTERNAL-IP"

# assuming `s` is your string
d = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=KEY)[VALUE].to_dict()
```

Alternatively, if you need a pure python approach, you can [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) the lines/cols of your string :

```
import re

header, *rows = [re.split(r"\s+", l.strip()) for l in s.strip().split("\n")]
    
d = {row[header.index(KEY)]: row[header.index(VALUE)] for row in rows}
```

Output :

```
>>> print(d)

{'cp-node-1': 'xxx', 'cp-node-2': 'yyy', 'cp-node-3': 'zzz'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The space-delimited input can be conveniently parsed into a dict by `csv.DictReader` with the delimiter set to a space and the option to skip initial spaces enabled:

```
from csv import DictReader
from io import StringIO
from operator import itemgetter

file = StringIO('''  NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP        
 cp-node-1                                   Ready    control-plane   xxx   xxx       xxx     
 cp-node-2                                   Ready    control-plane   xxx   xxx       yyy   
 cp-node-3                                   Ready    control-plane   xxx   xxx       zzz   ''')

print(dict(map(itemgetter('NAME', 'INTERNAL-IP'),
    DictReader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True))))
```

This outputs:

```
{'cp-node-1': 'xxx', 'cp-node-2': 'yyy', 'cp-node-3': 'zzz'}
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVKxboMwEN35ittsJBjaLF0YkIoipAQqoN0tuKSngG0ZtwJ@nppWJHTLkBtOz373nmU/69F@Krl70WaeT0Z1UPffQJ1WxsIr1bZA0aDxfilSK1NaQ/Kc5n/7SqMRVpmVJYvdGa11Ou9ELUJ0FXDGGEAWHxO4r8oqrt5LB4r8kJQbIt4vFh9JUaZ55lCaVUmRxYcwfVtHPKh1KFWD4dMdJy03HRdQK2mNakPdColuPQzDtcMG3eyfH2k/juM/890jzadpct2F4HuedpFY3riQeSc0v6XG2RIQC4BtHpX5weZD8CXXABpsqXNCEzFw8/2FNEmyJNpeixqjynyh72qefwA)